# Libgdx Drag a 3D model Instance on a 2D stage image in Android

Tags: android, 3d, drag-and-drop, libgdx, stage

To be simple, I should drag and drop a model 3D in front of a 2d image stage. When the two elements are superposed, a trigger that add 1 points happen.

[image: Example]

I wonder how I can make this trigger happen? with the position int the screen?

Thank you!